# Swift ios make a generic input type with multiple type

Tags: ios, swift, struct, datamodel

I would like to defined a variable with multiple type, but i fail in this case. I want to use it as UITextfield or UIButton in other way. Please help

```
struct FieldsModel {
    let input: [UITextField, UIButton]
}
```

Comment: try let input: [Any]

Comment: I want to use some UITextField or UIButton function when passing input into my function. But i dont want to cast it to Textfield or button

Comment: A variable can't have multiple types. Perhaps you could explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve.  `UIKit` types are classes, so there is an inheritance hierarchy that you may be able to use, or perhaps you could use an `enum` with associated values, but the chances are at some point you are going to need to cast to the concrete type in order to access specific properties and methods.

Comment: I can defined one more field in Struct. but a lot of items dont use this field. it will be a lot of null

Comment: Is `input` supposed to be an array or a single object?

Answer (score 1):

You can give only 1 type to a variable . The variation in your question is not valid.You can't assing 1..n datatype to a variable . You can use property of the structure generic . Maybe you want something like that

```
struct FieldsModel<T> {
    let input: [T]
}

let structWithButton = FieldsModel<UIButton>(input: [yourButtons])
let structWithTextField = FieldsModel<UITextField>(input: [yourTextfield])
```

Comment: While it isn't clear what the OP is actually trying to do, generics probably aren't a great fit since generic types are not covariant

Comment: What about restricting what T can be?

Comment: That is what the other answer does, but you will still likely have a problem with covariance.  You can't have a function that accepts `FieldsModel` as a parameter or a property of type `FieldsModel`. `FieldsModel<UIButton>` and `FieldsModel<UITextField>` are distinct types.

Answer (score 0):

```swift
struct FieldsModel<Control: UIControl> {
  let input: Control
}

let buttonModel: FieldsModel<UIButton>
let textFieldModel: FieldsModel<UITextField>
```

Comment: While it isn't clear what the OP is actually trying to do, generics probably aren't a great fit since generic types are not covariant.  What benefit do you get using a generic container over the superclass `UIControl`?

Comment: You might be right; that's why I just posted the code and figured we'd get feedback if the OP wants to work through it. But constrained extension of `Control` may solve the problem "i dont want to cast it to Textfield or button".